# How to optimize this GORM query

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a query which makes 2 database queries.  I am new to GORM and don't know how to optimize it into 1 query using criteria, or a where clause or something else.  I'm using springsecurity as well and have a User class for login security.  I have a Profile class with a User object:

```
class Profile {
   User user
}
```

In my controller the session stores the user id.  When I want to load the profile to update it my code is currently:

```
def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id) // 1st db query
def domainObject = Profile.findByUser(user) // 2nd db query
```

I've tried a few query variations through trial and error but can't seem to find one that doesn't generate an error.  This seems like it would be trivial.  The pseudo-query would be 'get me the profile for the profile.user that has this user id'.

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions. This is required for this community to work :-)

Comment: Answer accepted now.  I was unaware of that feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `load` method to avoid the first database query:

```
def user = User.load(springSecurityService.principal.id)
def domainObject = Profile.findByUser(user)
```

This works because `load` doesn't trigger a database lookup until you access any property other than the `id`, but that's all that's needed for the `findByUser` since it's the foreign key.

Answer (score 4):

I would do:

```
def profile = Profile.createCriteria().list {
    user{
        eq 'id',springSecurityService.principal.id
    }
}[0]
```

Or

```
def profile = Profile.executeQuery('select p from Profile p where p.user.id = :userId',[userId:springSecurityService.principal.id])[0]
```

Comment: You should accept one of the answers, I believe Burts proposal fits better here.