# How to write this Grails GORM Hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

New to GORM, can't figure how to do this query.  Here are my domain classes (minus unnecessary info):

```
User {...} //domain object (from springsecurity)

BasicProfile {
   User user
   static hasMany = [applicants:Applicant]
}

Applicant {
   static belongsTo = BasicProfile
   int applicantNumber
}
```

My BasicProfile will always have 1 or 2 Applicants.  Right now I'm using a hasMany, though I may switch to having an applicant1 and applicant2 in the BasicProfile at a later time.

What I am trying to get in pseudo sql:

select the applicant object from a BasicProfile where the applicantNumber = 1 and BasicProfile.user.id == springSecurityService.principal.id

Basically I'm trying to get back one of the Applicant objects from the BasicProfile, given the session user and an applicantNumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
User user = User.load(springSecurityService.principal.id)
def applicant = BasicProfile.findByUser(user)
                            .applicants?.find{it.applicantNumber == 1}
```

Inspired by [Burt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18702591/2051952) and using dynamicFinders.

Comment: In this case maybe HQL is better, because you will load all applicants to get one.

Comment: @SérgioMichels As a matter of fact, basicProfile will have only and only 2 applicants max, as mentioned by OP. :)

Comment: @user2636133 Accept if it was useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
User user = User.get(...) //get's the user instance
BasicProfile.createCriteria().get {
  eq('user', user)
  applicants {
    eq('applicantNumber', 1) //filter by applicantNumber
  }
}
```

Comment: This returns a BasicProfile object.  The query should be for an Applicant object that has the BasicProfile as a parent.

Comment: Oh right, you need the applicant. Go with @dmahapatro's answer.